# Reading XML with Namespace in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm working on an WinRT App and I should ready some XML with a namespace in it. Now this was ok with the old .NET, but now there is no XmlDocument.NameTable anymore. So how can I create an XmlNamespaceManager?

```
var XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

XmlDoc.Load(new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read));
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("s", "http://api.facebook.com/1.0/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *much* easier to handle namespaces with LINQ to XML, which I believe is what you can use in Windows 8:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
XNamespace ns = "http://api.facebook.com/1.0/";
XElement element = doc.Root.Element(ns + "foo");
```

Read a good LINQ to XML introduction or tutorial, and you should see how to handle namespaces - but it really is significantly simpler than with `XmlDocument`. You simply don't need namespace managers any more! (There may be *some* cases where they're still useful - I'm not sure - but I certainly can't remember using them myself with LINQ to XML.)

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but Element(...) method throws: "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."

Comment: Ahh: overloaded + operator: `Element(XName.Get("foo", "http://api.facebook.com/1.0/"))`